# What is しか here?

Tags: conjugations, classical-japanese, auxiliaries

> [至誠]{しせい}に[悖]{もと}る[勿]{な}かり**しか**
>   [言行]{げんこう}に[恥]{は}づる[勿]{な}かり**しか**...

What part of speech is it?

[Wiki](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E7%9C%81) translates it as 真心に反する点はなかったか, which going by meaning only fits with 2（連語） [here](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B), but I couldn't find examples where し 副助詞 follows 連用形. Is it the しか（終助詞）? If it's き 已然形, why is it 已然形?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's direct past [き](https://classicaljapanese.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/ki/) + question [か](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B) (see the 係助詞 one).

The particle か causes [係【かか】り結【むす】び](http://www.thomasdougherty.net/?p=114) phenomenon, which makes the sentence verb end in 連体形 no matter where か attaches to in the sentence. In the link about き above you can see its 連体形 is し.

Comment: I thought maybe it was 係り結び （～こそ　～已然形） with the first part omitted, but this answer sounds simpler and more plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's the 已然形 of [き](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8D-471819) (a classical helper verb that expresses reflection on real past experience c.f. けり).

Comment: Could you explain why it's 已然形?